# How to get column name in SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2005, iis-6

I'm trying get column name (IIS, SQL server PHP) from table.
I need to check value exist in db or no if exist i need get column name. But i neet to check 3 diferent columns in same table.

```
$sql = "SELECT bag_code, box_code, date_code 
        FROM packing 
        WHERE bag_code='$code_verification' OR box_code='$code_verification' 
        OR date_code='$code_verification'";
```

I am struck at writing a query.i searched and didn't find any solution to this. Here i want to show the column name based on some specific value

```
For Instance , My table is like.
id  | fruits   |vegetables    |softdrink
-----------------------
1   | apple    | Onion        | Pepsi
2   | mango    | Potato       | Coke    
3   | banana   | Bringal      | RedBull
```

if i have a value "mango", then i should get the column name as fruit or

if i have a value "RedBull", then i should get the column name as softdrink

Comment: Basic method is to use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) or PDO's [`rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: I don't understand your question then. A column is a row. If you want to check if a record exists under a "column", then you use `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){...}` or `$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query); if($numrows > 0){...}` other than that, you will need to be clearer about your question.

Comment: Please see my question

Comment: you've structured your database wrong.

Comment: ah ok, I understand now. Then you could use and select columns as an alias then, using the `AS` keyword. I.e.: `SELECT column_name AS alias_name` or `SELECT column1 AS alias1, column2 AS alias2 FROM table` - Refer to the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

Comment: what database you are using "mysql" or "sql server"

Comment: Fred -i- could you write by my example?

Comment: I believe I just did above, see the MySQL link also. Plus, I can't write you code, I'm headed to bed. Someone might come along and help, but I can't right now.

Comment: give as an example output.

Comment: Viscocent why structure is bad?

Comment: should be ` id | item | type ` or ` id | item | type_id `

Comment: @klapsius give us an example output what what do you want to achieve

Comment: could you write down the code what you are using right now?

Comment: Viscocent You mean vertical structure not horizontal. change DB with tipe of record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Restructure your Table

*you will have a lot of trouble in the future if you continue this type of table structure.*

currently you have this:

```
id  | fruits   |vegetables    |softdrink
----+----------+--------------+----------
1   | apple    | Onion        | Pepsi
2   | mango    | Potato       | Coke    
3   | banana   | Bringal      | RedBull
```

youve probably thought: 
`SELECT fruits FROM table` is easy right?

this is wrong;

you have to do it like this:

**items**

```
id  | item_name| item_type_id |
----+----------+--------------+
1   | apple    | 1            |
2   | mango    | 1            | 
3   | banana   | 1            |
4   | Onion    | 2            |
5   | Potato   | 2            |
6   | Bringal  | 2            |
7   | Pepsi    | 3            |
8   | Coke     | 3            |
9   | RedBull  | 3            |
```

**item_type**

```
id  | item_type   | 
----+-------------+
1   | fruits      | 
2   | vegestables | 
3   | softdrinks  | 

SELECT * FROM table WHERE item_type_id = 1 /*selects all fruits*/
```

Once you've structured your table.
this will be the **Answer** for your **Question**:

```
SELECT it.item_type FROM items i INNER JOIN USING(i.item_type_id = it.id) WHERE i.item_name LIKE '%mango%'
```

this will return `fruits`.